# How to create two plc project in one Project on Twincat 3

Tags: plc, twincat

As described in the picture, I want to have two plc projects, sendingMQTT and receiving MQTT in my project. How can I do this?

Project structure
[image: Project structure]

Comment: Do you mean that you want help figuring out how to make the MQTT Send back and forth? This is a very vague request, so some more details and indications of your own efforts so far would be helpful.
But you may be able to start looking at the [Beckhoff MQTT](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6701_tc3_iot_communication_mqtt/3518541195.html&id=) library samples section.

Comment: No, I just want to create two sub plc project in one project tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ### To create a new PLC project
>
> 1. Select the command New > Project in the menu File.
> 2. Select the template TwinCAT Projects > TwinCAT XAE Project and enter a name, for example here "Sample Project" and a storage location in the file system.
> 3. Quit the dialog with OK.
> 4. Mark the PLC object in the project tree and select the command Add New Item... in the menu Project or in the context menu.
> 5. Select the Standard PLC Project in the category Plc Templates and enter a name (here once again "Sample Project").
> 6. Quit the dialog with Add.

Per the [Beckhoff Infosys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2526130571.html&id=4976456402045339007) explains how to create a new PLC project.

**To add a second PLC project to an existing project, you need to perform steps 4, 5 & 6 a second time.**